# File lock between host and guest

Tags: bash, shell, file, locking, virtualbox

I'm struggling with a niche case that should be simple...

I'm running mint on virtualbox on a windows host. There is a third-party remote server running windows server (2012 or 2016) and writing files to a NAS folder.

The remote server will write a large file and save it on the NAS folder, then my guest (linux) will be probing the folder for any changes and move the files to another folder and run a script.

Probing for the folder and running my script all works fine.

**The issue is, how do I check if the server is still writing (file lock) to the file from within my guest OS?**

I know file locks are OS dependent, and even implementation dependent, but is this behavior completely impossible? Should I just re-write my code for windows (probably Java) and forget about shell-script (was going to re-use previous code already working).

thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You need some other synchronisation method.  Even if you could check file locks  then you might check just before the lock is obtained.  That means you need an *atomic* action in the shell - there are none.  I have used fifo's for synchronisation between shared drives on different operating systems, but you have to think the sequence through very carefully.

Comment: So you're saying that there is no way in shell to check if a file is locked by another process? 

Is there any other process you know that could work? What if the shared folder was native in the Linux machine and there is no virtualbox? Just a linux machine having a shared network drive that another server (running windows) writes to?

Comment: *So you're saying that there is no way in shell to check if a file is locked by another process?* Even if there is, "check for a lock, if no lock use the file" is a [TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  "Check for X before doing Y" is almost always a bad idea.  You need to find a way to pass information from the file writer that it's done writing the file.  Renaming the file or moving it from one directory to another in the same file system can be used to do that since those are atomic operations.

Comment: Renaming the file or moving it from one directory to another in the same file system can be used to do that since those are atomic operations.

So, if I try to move from one dir to another while the file is still open, it fails right? and then I cna use the exit code or something else to chekc if it succeeded or failed?

Comment: @user2823183: its worse than that, but does depend on the operating system.  On UNIX-like systems if a file is open then another process (with relevant permissions) moves the file to another directory then it will *work*.  The first process will be unaware of this.  The original file will not be visible to another process but will not actually be "removed" (a subjective term) until there are no longer any open file descriptors connected.

Comment: I'll add that file locks only work between *co-operating* processes - they are discretionary.  So if any process (which has permissions) wants to ignore file locks it can.  Some old UNIXs had mandatory file locks maintained by kernel, but this has been abandoned because of performance issues.